# Gap:$\;\;L(90,28) := {\{n90 - m28 ∈ N, n, m ∈ N, n < 28\}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Which elements of the sets Gap:$$L(90,28) := {\{n90 - m28 ∈ N, n, m ∈ N, n < 28\}}$$ $$$$What would be a quick way to resolve?

Comment: We have $gcd(90,28)=2$

Comment: Try small cases, were you can do all the work by hand. For example with $(14,4)$ in place of $(90,28)$. And why not $(10,4)$, $(10,3)$! You will observe that the set looks quite regular, but there are exceptions at the high end. The greatest common divisor will play a role. Do this first. Report on your experiments, and then you can expect more help. For somewhat related background reading (though the situation is a bit reversed there) check out [Numerical semigroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup) from Wikipedia. Don't take that too literally, as this is different!